# Enable PanGesture Recognizer for collection View with horizontal and vertical scrolling content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, uipangesturerecognizer

I am using `UIPageViewController` for showing different viewControllers as tabs.

In my child view controllers I have vertical as well as horizontal scrolling content, so I think `UIPageViewController` is disabling Pan Gesture.

So I am not able to change current view by swiping left or right.

My pageViewController also returns `nil` for `self.pageController.gestureRecognizers`

I know that `UIPageViewController` already has `UIPanGesture` to change views.

So how can I enable or achieve swipe to change view in my `UIPageViewController`?

[image]

According to screenshot I have tabs at the top and my child view controllers are vertical scrolling and I have few sections with horizontal scrolling content.

Any help would be much appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: That is a bit confusing... You have *"vertical + horizontal scrolling content"*, and you are *"not able to change current view by swiping"*. Does this mean your scrolling content **does** scroll? Maybe if you show an image of how you have the "pages" designed?

Comment: Please check my updated question.

Comment: It looks like a fairly complex hierarchy --- I think you need to dig a little deeper in your code to see what might be causing the issue. I just added a `UIScrollView` to a page in a `UIPageViewController` and have no problem scrolling its content (both horizontal and vertical), as well as swiping from page to page, so it's possible something else is intercepting the gestures.

Comment: I am using UICollectionView for showing both horizontal and vertical scrolling content and that collectionView is added inside UIViewController.

Comment: @DonMag, the problem is I am using UICollectionView as childviewcontrollers which has vertical and horizontal scrolling content, so I think its disabling UIPageViewController's swipe gesture to change page.

Comment: So how can I have pan gesture to change page with swipe?

Comment: You have horizontal scrolling collection view as the page content of a page view controller... so you want to scroll the collection view left/right ***and*** scroll the page view left/right, all with the same gesture? How will the user indicate *"I want to scroll the items"* or *"I want to scroll the page"*?